# excel VBA loop then copy based on condition

Tags: excel, vba

I am absolutely a novice when it comes to macros and VBA and need some help.

I have a workbook with 6 worksheets. The first work sheet ("All Grants FY15") has 5 columns ("Date", "Grant", "Type", "Amount" and "Category", A2:E2). I am using this worksheet to enter all grant expenses. The remaining worksheets ("City ESG", "County ESG", "CoC HMIS", "SSVF HMIS", and "HMIS Program Fees") have the same columns at the same placement. In each of these subsequent worksheets, I have the name of the grant (which matches the value that will be placed on "All Grants FY15", B2:B500) placed at F2.

I am looking for a way to loop through "All Grants FY15", read the value at B2:B500, and copy that row into the next blank row on the corresponding worksheet where F2 on that worksheet equals B2 on the "All Grants FY15".

Does that make sense?
A

Comment: Also, I need it not to duplicate the previous row copies every time I run it.

Comment: Have you looked at using the `VLOOKUP` function?

Comment: I just tried, but I can't figure out how to use vlookup for copy an entire row over.

Comment: Do your columns in "All Grants FY15" need to be in the order you have listed? And can you add a column at the end if necessary?

Comment: Does the reference to F2 stay constant? or change with the rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added an IF statement to check in column "F" on the source sheet for a 0 or 1 to test if already moved.  When it gets moved, a 1 is marked in column "F" (ie, col #6).  Since you only have 5 columns needing to be moved, I got rid of the lastCol variable and iserted From lCol 1 To 5 instead of lastCol.  If something doesn't get copied, there will not be a 1 in column "F" and it's probably because none of the sheets has a value = to Column "B" -Grant.

```
Sub GrantCopy()

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastTRow As Long    'Last Target Row
Dim tRow As Long        'Target Row
Dim source As String    'The source sheet
Dim target As String    'Variable target sheet
Dim tempVal As String   'Hold value of Source!B2
Dim ws As Worksheet

source = "ALL Grants FY15"
lastRow = Sheets(source).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For lRow = 3 To lastRow                 'Loop through source sheet
        If Sheets(source).Cells(lRow, "F").Value < 1 Then 'Check to make sure not already moved
            tempVal = Sheets(source).Cells(lRow, "B").Text

            For Each ws In Worksheets             'Loop through all sheets
                If ws.Name <> source Then       'Make sure not checking Source sheet
                    target = ws.Name

                    If Sheets(target).Range("F2").Text = tempVal Then      'Does "B(row)" = F2
                        lastTRow = Sheets(target).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row  'Get Last Row
                        tRow = lastTRow + 1             'Set new Row 1 after last

                        For lCol = 1 To 5        'Copy cells from one sheet to another loop columns
                            Sheets(target).Cells(tRow, lCol) = Sheets(source).Cells(lRow, lCol).Value
                        Next lCol
                        Sheets(source).Cells(lRow, "F") = 1   'Mark row as having been moved with a "1"
                    End If
                End If
            Next ws
        End If
    Next lRow
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am getting a Run-time error 424 (object required) at For Each ws In Workbook ... ideas?

Comment: @AmandaShipp.  I mistakenly typed each ws in Workbook needs to be "in Worksheets"

Comment: Unless I misunderstood your intentions.  The above code looks at each row of ALL Grants, then goes through each other sheet, and if the value from the current row of the ALL GRANTS loop (B:row) matches the target sheets "F2", it will add a new row to the end of the target and copy the whole row.

Comment: that TOTALLY worked!! is there anything we can add to the script to prevent it from duplicating rows each time i run the script?

Comment: maybe it didn't work... now it's only copying over the 1st column...??

Comment: It's because your header row isn't row 1.  So when it loops, it's going from 'lCol = 1 To lastCol', and 'lastCol = 1' because no headers exist beyond the merged cell that spans the sheet.  The way to find this sort of problem is to open your LOCALS window and step through the code, see where the values are set.  I noticed lCol was "1" (which it should be 5), and then looked to see where it gets assigned, Row 1, you have headers on 2..  Also, our loop should start at row 3, not 2. Correcting.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

In the "All Grants FY15" sheet, add a column after the "Category" column to duplicate your date column using `=A2`. To extend this formula to the last used row, double-click on the little square in the bottom-right-hand corner of the cell containing the first formula.

Step 2:

In each remaining worksheet, in the "Date" column, add the following formula in the first cell under the header:

`=VLOOKUP($B2,Sheet1!$B$2:$F$500,5)` - Change "Sheet1" as necessary

In the three columns after the "Grant" column - "Type", "Amount", and "Category" - add the following formulas:

`=VLOOKUP($B2,Sheet1!$B$2:$F$500,2)` - Change "Sheet1" as necessary

`=VLOOKUP($B2,Sheet1!$B$2:$F$500,3)` - Change "Sheet1" as necessary

`=VLOOKUP($B2,Sheet1!$B$2:$F$500,4)` - Change "Sheet1" as necessary

**NOTE:** If some of your "Date" cells may be blank on the "All Grants FY15" sheet, change the formula to `=IF(ISBLANK(A2),"",A2)`

If any of your data on the "All Grants FY15" sheet may be blank, change the remaining formulas to:

`=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($B2,Sheet1!$B$2:$F$500,5)),"",VLOOKUP($B2,Sheet1!$B$2:$F$500,5))`

`=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($B2,Sheet1!$B$2:$F$500,5)),"",VLOOKUP($B2,Sheet1!$B$2:$F$500,2))`

`=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($B2,Sheet1!$B$2:$F$500,5)),"",VLOOKUP($B2,Sheet1!$B$2:$F$500,3))`

`=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($B2,Sheet1!$B$2:$F$500,5)),"",VLOOKUP($B2,Sheet1!$B$2:$F$500,4))`

**EXAMPLE**

Here's an example to give you a better idea of where these formulas get placed:

"All Grants FY15" sheet:

```
       A        B        C         D           E           F
1  Date       Grant     Type     Amount     Category    (blank)
2  1/12/2014  abcd      efgh     1234       ijkl        1/12/2014
3             BCDE      FGHI     2345       JKLM
                                                           ^
                                                           |
                                                           |
                                                  =IF(ISBLANK(A2),"",A2)
```

"City ESG" sheet:

```
       A        B        C         D           E
1  Date       Grant     Type     Amount     Category
2  1/12/2014  abcd      efgh     1234       ijkl
3             BCDE      FGHI     2345       JKLM
       ^                  ^        ^          ^
       |                  |        |          |
       |                  |        |          |
       |                  |        |    =IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($B2,'All Grants FY15'!$B$2:$F$13,4)),"",VLOOKUP($B2,'All Grants FY15'!$B$2:$F$13,4))
       |                  |        |
       |                  |    =IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($B2,'All Grants FY15'!$B$2:$F$13,3)),"",VLOOKUP($B2,'All Grants FY15'!$B$2:$F$13,3))
       |                  |
       |              =IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($B2,'All Grants FY15'!$B$2:$F$13,2)),"",VLOOKUP($B2,'All Grants FY15'!$B$2:$F$13,2))
       |
   =IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($B2,'All Grants FY15'!$B$2:$F$13,5)),"",VLOOKUP($B2,'All Grants FY15'!$B$2:$F$13,5))
```

Obviously for cell B3, the "$B2" would be changed to "$B3" and so on.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it just doesn't work for some reason. I'm using the formulas you've created (modified for my workbook), but it keeps pulling the wrong cell information to the sub. worksheets. the formula i'm using in City ESG B3, for example, =IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP("ESG City of Mobile 2014",'All Grants FY15'!$B$3:$B$500,5)),"",VLOOKUP("ESG City of Mobile 2014",'All Grants FY15'!$B$3:$B$500,1)).... I changed $B2 to $F2 at first, because I wanted it to look for the value in F2, but it wouldn't. I then tried the actual text in F2 ("ESG City of Mobile 2014") but to no avail.

Comment: Is "ESG City of Mobile 2014" the value in the "Grant" column that you want to look up in the "All Grants FY15" sheet?

Comment: It is. In the example formula I sent you, it's returning CoC HMIS 2014 (another grant in the Grant column) AND it's row.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include an example. Hopefully that helps you on this one.